# What does it mean in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

i'm trying to learn Matlab but i don't understand what does this writing means:
**sauv(:, 2:2:2*N)** ? It is written bellow:

```
subplot(2,2,[1, 2])
plot(sauv(:, 2:2:2*N), sauv(:, 3:2:(2*N+1)),couleur,'LineWidth',2, 'MarkerSize', 2)
grid('on')
hold on
subplot(223)
plot(sauv(:, 1)/Nmax, sauv(:, 2:2:2*N),couleur,'LineWidth',2, 'MarkerSize', 2)
grid('on')
hold on
subplot(224)
plot(sauv(:, 1)/Nmax, sauv(:, 3:2:(2*N+1)),couleur,'LineWidth',2, 'MarkerSize', 2)
grid('on')
hold on
```

I get that sauv is an empty array which is filled as the calculation ran.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on the Matlab [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

If I have a matrix like this:

```
A = magic(5)

A =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
    4    6   13   20   22
   10   12   19   21    3
   11   18   25    2    9
```

And I want to get the whole of column 1 then I can use the `:` operator to tell Matlab that I want all the rows:

```
A(:,3)

ans = 

    1
    7
    13
    19
    25
```

but I can also use it to create a vector with constant increments. So if I want a vector like this `[1,2,3,4,5]` I can actually just go `1:5`. But if I want only every second number then I use two colons: `1:2:5` gives us `[1,3,5]`. The middle number tells Matlab how much to increment by.

So putting it together `A(:, 2:2:5)` will choose all the rows by only the even columns because it is the same as `A(:, [2,4])` which gives us

```
ans =

   24    8
    5   14
    6   20
   12   21
   18    2
```